# PyQt5: Moving QTableView rows up and down - segmentation fault error on down but works on up?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a simple GUI in PyQt5 that uses a QTableView to display a list of incidents. I am trying to change the order of these incidents by clicking the up and down buttons. I want the selected row to either move up one or down one row from where it is when the respective button is pressed.

However, I am having issues with my `on_move_down_button_clicked` slot method. It keeps crashing the app with a `segmentation fault` error. The `on_move_up_button_clicked` method works as intended. Using the debugger, I determined that the `self.endMoveRows()` is where the app crashes. I do not have that method overriden in my `IncidentTableModel` class.

I cannot figure out why the down button method is not working. I found this post [here](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/43640-beginMoveRows-working-down-to-up-but-not-up-to-down-Any-insignt-would-be-great) which seems to be the same problem I am having. However, the solution is not very clear and in C++. Any help or insight into why I have this problem and how to solve it would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

```
class IncidentTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
     def moveRow(self, source_row, destination_row):

        if destination_row > -1 and destination_row < len(self.incidents):

            self.beginMoveRows(
                QModelIndex(),
                source_row,
                source_row,
                QModelIndex(),
                destination_row,
            )
            incident = self.incidents.pop(source_row)
            self.incidents.insert(destination_row, incident)

            self.endMoveRows()
        return True

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # Works
    def on_move_up_button_clicked(self):
        """Move selected table row up in table"""
        index = self.table_view.currentIndex()
        row = index.row()
        if row != -1:
            self.table_model.moveRow(row, row - 1)
            self.table_view.update()

    # Segmentation Fault Errors
    def on_move_down_button_clicked(self):
        """Move selected table row down in table"""
        index = self.table_view.currentIndex()

        if index.row() != -1 and index.row() < len(self.incidents) - 1:
            # index.row() + 2, will work but will skip one row (not desired).
            self.table_model.moveRow(index.row(), index.row() + 1) 
            self.table_view.update()
            index = self.table_view.currentIndex()
```

Comment: It's probably due to the fact that you're popping an index and then adding it without considering the removal. But we cannot be certain, and we wouldn't review your code to make it work (that's on your part), so: 1. try to run your code in a terminal or prompt, as IDEs may give false positive and be unable to show the full traceback; 2. please provide a valid and complete [mre].

Comment: What do you mean? How should I consider the removal?

Comment: The destination argument of `beginMoveRows()` should be based on the current target position *before* the item has been [re]moved: considering a simple list such as `a, b, c` if you want to move `a` after `b`, the destination will not be 1, but 2 (the index after `b`, prior the removal of `a`). See the examples in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginMoveRows) (specifically, the last one).